# How can I make a workflow check a list field for existing data?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I want to use a workflow to populate a particular field in a list using data drawn from several other fields. 
I have set up the second part of the workflow with no problem but I need to know if there is a way to get a workflow to check if a field contains existing data. I will then use an IF/Else statement to either use the existing data or fill in the blank field.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do so in SharePoint Designer workflow and check if the field contains data or not, you can then build a string in the designer calculated from all other fields and set the value for your field with your string. So yes that's doable.

Comment: I was hoping you might tell me HOW to check if a field contains data.

Comment: In your workflow, you can use a "Condition" action of type : if any value equals any value, from the ribbon. Then inside the condition choose: If Current item from the first droppdown list, and choose your column from the second drop down list, click ok. Then choose the condition itself to be either empty or not empty as you would prefer. That's it.